# Unable to stream from MJPEG server

Tags: html, webkit, video-streaming, html5-video, mjpeg

I am trying to stream from MJPEG server by using `<video>` but i get following error:

```
HTTP "Content-Type" of "multipart/x-mixed-replace" is not supported. Load of media resource http://localhost:8080/stream?topic=/gscam/image_raw?height=240?width=320 failed.
```

With following HTML code:

```
<video src="http://localhost:8080/stream?topic=/gscam/image_raw?height=240?width=320" id="vid"
       height="240" width="320">
</video>
```

I tried in Firefox and Chrome without any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way to embed MJPEG streams into Firefox and Chrome are with an  tag.